# Issue after Log in, in sandbox paypal, 'Spree gem' Braitree Payments Sandbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

hello every im building an ecommerce site and im using Braintre to payments. the software versions are:

- gem 'spree', '~> 3.2.0'
- gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.2.0.beta'
- gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.2.0.beta'
- gem 'spree_braintree_vzero', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_braintree_vzero'

> all works fine when im log in in the application.

but

> if im desconnected in the application doesn't work. for example:

after i clicked "paypal checkout" button and added the sandbox credentials i got this issue:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/checkout/registration.action=edit&controller=spree%252Fcheckout&paypal_email=comprador-programmer%2540codigo.com&state=address"
```

i think the easiest solution is remove the button in the url: localhost:3000/cart, because if i remove the button in that url i have to log in before to add the sandbox credentials.

> but the question is how?

### thanks a lot i hope your answer my friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go to editing PayPal (where the credentials were), scroll down to advanced settings, click it to open the panel and set `PAYPAL DISPLAY ON CART:` to `DISABLED`.